# How to decrease the memory usage in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, memory-management

When I upload my project on the online hosting server, the entry processes usage goes to 100%. It results to website down.

**Using**

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

I got this result.

MEMORY USAGE
1,263,856 bytes

Even a single page takes 1.2 MB

How can I solve my this problem, Please Help

Comment: by disabling the profiler?

Comment: 1,2 mb is nothing, compared to other frameworks, you certainly have some other issues ...

Comment: Disable the profiler and use the browser development tools to determine load times. Auto loading only costs when a library or helper is actually used. You must have some code that is looping into eternity

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. Maybe just make sure you aren't loading things where they aren't actually needed (like autoload loads things for each request whether you utilize it or not). CI actually has one of the smallest memory footprints of any a framework. All frameworks take more overhead than straight PHP. Try benchmarking the same thing in another framework and it will most likely use more memory than CI does

Comment: I am just auto loading the form library and usermodel, 1 row of a table(model)

Comment: where you loaded the model and library?